# RS HMP4040 doesn't answer on emulated COM port

Tags: power-supply, remote-control

I try to control my [NMP4040](https://www.rohde-schwarz.com/hu/product/hmp4000-productstartpage_63493-47360.html) via USB-emulated serial COM port.

I have downloaded the [driver](https://scdn.rohde-schwarz.com/ur/pws/dl_downloads/dl_driver/hameg/usb_drivers/HO720-HO730-Interface-Driver-2_12_28.zip) from [here](https://www.rohde-schwarz.com/us/driver/hmp4040/). And I have assigned the driver to the device:

[image]

I have connected to `COM3` with PuTTY:

[image]

The terminal comes up, but it does not answer for any command. I try to enter `*IDN?`, which should echo the *Identification Query*, based on [this manual](https://cdn.rohde-schwarz.com/pws/dl_downloads/dl_common_library/dl_manuals/gb_1/h/hmp_serie/HMP_SCPI_ProgrammersManual_en_01.pdf).

What did I wrong?

Comment: perhaps incorrect putty flow control

Comment: I would use no flow control, at least for initial tests.  Also, try exchanging the TX/RX connections - it should be TX->RX, RS<-TX, but try TX->TX, RX->RX as well.

Comment: There is no TX, and RX in emulated COM ports.

Comment: I've tried with no flow control, but still nothing

Comment: I can access the device with the RsVisaTester 5.8.5, only with the Rohde and Swarz Visa implementation.